# Change sleep function - java - android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I set a sleep() in the beginning of my code, and later on the code I want to change the time: delay or precede, depends on if term.

for example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread background = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                sleep(10000);


                Intent i;

               i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),Activity8.class);


                startActivity(i);

                finish();

            } catch (Exception ex) { }

        }
    };

 if (connect.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || connect.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING || connect.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
      connect.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
     network = true; }


       if (network == true) {
           // I want to set sleep to 2 seconds instead of 10 (current setting is 10). 
       } else { // I don't want to change sleep }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an int to store the amount of time to sleep for somewhere in the class and then modify that for however long you want to sleep for. However this would not update the current sleep. The only way I can think of to combat that would be to interupt the thread and then start it again with the new sleep time. For example:

```
int sleepTime = 10000;
Thread background;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.splash);

background = new Thread() {
    public void run() {

        try {
            sleep(sleepTime);


            Intent i;

           i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),Activity8.class);


            startActivity(i);

            finish();

        } catch (Exception ex) { }

    }
};

 if (connect.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || connect.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING || connect.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
  connect.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
   network = true;
  }


   if (network == true) {
       sleepTime = 2000;
       background.interrupt();
       background.start();
   } else {
       sleepTime = 10000;
       background.interrupt();
       background.start();
   }
```

I am not sure if this would work. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: when I call  background.start(); the app crashes